# granted table with select but procedure doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table granted with SELECT - so I can access the table with select..

I can also create copy of this table with:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
SELECT *
FROM read_only_tbl;
```

And also manualy reloadtable ->

```
DELETE FROM my_table;
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT *
FROM read_only_tbl;
```

But when I want to run the "reload" from procedure it gives me an error while compiling that the procedure can't see the "read_only_table"...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prcd_reload AS
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM my_table;
    INSERT INTO my_table
    SELECT *
    FROM read_only_tbl;

   /*** .. rest of code ***/

END;
/
```

-> *PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*

what grant do I need to access that table in procedure?

Comment: In order to access the table in a procedure, select must have been granted to the user directly and not through a role.

Comment: @Tarun:  that's right :) because the SELECT was granted to the role (not directly to the user)

Comment: This [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1065832643319) might help u to understand that better

Comment: @Crazy2crack: thx, I'll go through it

Answer (score 0):

Thx for @Tarun !!

His answer was correct:

> In order to access the table in a procedure, select must have been
>   granted to the user directly and not through a role.